# Not sure how to change panel to have display mode of overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, panel

Sorry, i'm a beginner to all this but i'm not sure how to change it so that the panel will overlay (so it appears over the pages contents instead of pushing it to the side). i've tried changing the display to overlay instead of push or reveal but it still doesn't work. The answer's probably really simple haha so thanks for helping :)

Link:https: //jsfiddle.net/jaffalina/jrqbuc3o/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="overlay">
```

Once you do that the panel appears to work as an overlay